# Setting useState within another useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am attempting to set the time (mm:ss) by taking separate inputs for mins and secs with one use of `useState` and combining them with another for keeping track of the overall form data, however I cannot seem to get the combined string to push into the form data...

I think I may be setting the data incorrectly somehow...

```
const Modal = ({show, handleClose, handleAdd, children}) => {
    const today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    let initialFormState = {
        date: today,
        distance: '5.23',
        time: ''
    };
    let initialTimeState = {
        mins: 0,
        secs: 0
    };

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormState);
    const [timeData, setTimeData] = useState(initialTimeState);

    const submitData = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log({timeData});

        // Add correctly formatted time to main formData
        const {mins, secs} = timeData;
        const time = `${mins}:${secs}`;
        setFormData({...formData, 'time': time});

        console.log(formData); // Here I can see that the 'time' field is empty...

    }

    return (
       ...
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Could simply store a reference to your new object and pass that into `setFormData()` and log it instead

Comment: @charlietfl - Could you give an example?

Comment: `const newData ={...formData, 'time': time}; setFormData(newData); console.log(newData );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setFormData` changes are happening asynchronously, unfortunately you won't see the modification immediately. Instead you can use `useEffect` hook to catch changes of your state.

Try as the following instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(formData);
}, [formData]);
```

Read further about `useEffect` hook at [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) link.

Comment: Hmm... This did what you described, however it appears to console.log out on loading also. And how would I integrate it with the `onSubmit`? This modal will push data back to a dashboard that will display it.

Comment: @physicsboy That should not cause any issues, your component will be rendered again once the `formData` is changed. So I think the changes should be reflected on the dashboard.

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm confused with how this should work. I understand that the useEffect will work, re-rendering when a change is detected, but I'm not sure how I would implement this to set the form state. When I move the `setFormData` line into the `useEffect` I get a warning aboutusing setData within useEffect. I'm a bit of a n00b at this React stuff.

Comment: Aha! I was being a bit of a numpty, sorry. It did take me a while and this other tutorial (https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetching-data-updating-state-hooks#module-usestate) to see that I should have had the dependency on `timeData` and put `setFormData({...formData, 'time': time})` in the `useEffect` function :-)

Comment: Thank you , your short description saved me 2 hours of search